# The methods xx and yy use the same SOAPAction

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl, asmx

We are trying to create a mock service for a web service for testing purposes.

To do this we run wsdl.exe to create an interface and then create an asmx web service based on that interface. We have done this several times over the last years without any problems.

This time we get an error:

The methods xx and yy use the same SOAPAction

When we call the web service. Have done some searching on google, it says that this is a bug with wsdl.exe. But says nothing about what to do about it.

Is there a way to fix this? Should I just delete parts of references.cs?

Thanks

Shiraz

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found the solution. Added the following line as an attribute to the web service class:

[SoapDocumentService(RoutingStyle=SoapServiceRoutingStyle.RequestElement)]

After a clean solution and a rebuild, everything worked.